# Custom spss table with missing value info and number of categories

Tags: customization, spss, missing-data

Complete SPSS beginner here. I am really lost trying to come up with a custom table. I have a few variables and I want the final table to look like:

```
Var_name  N_valid  N_missing N_categories Max_%_category
  Var1       X          Y          Z            W
  Var2       A          B          C            D
```

By Max_%_category I mean the percentage of the value that is repeated the most. So for this example data:

```
data list free / Var1 to Var4 (4F1.0).
begin data
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
2 1 3 1
. . 2 .
end data.
```

It would be:

```
Var_name  N_valid  N_missing N_categories Max_%_category
  Var1       4          1          3           50%
  Var3       5          0          4           40%
```

Is CTABLE the route? I couldn't find how to count N_valid and N_missing easily. The FREQUENCIES command sort of works but I don't know how to only create the first table with the missing info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone could probably help you with custom tables, but not being a big fan myself, here's a way to get the same results right in your data window:

```
data list free / Var1 to Var4 (4F1.0).
begin data
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
2 1 3 1
. . 2 .
end data.

dataset name origData.
dataset copy tmp.
dataset activate tmp.
varstocases /make val from var1 to var4/index=var(val)/null=keep.
aggregate out=*/break  var val/n=n.
if missing(val) msn=n.
if not missing(val) vld=n.
aggregate out=*/break=var/N_valid N_missing=sum(vld msn)/N_categories=n(vld)/Max_category_N=max(vld).
compute Max_category_P=Max_category_N/N_valid.
dataset name tab1.

*you can add a bit of formatting and corrections:.
compute Max_category_P=Max_category_P*100.
FORMATS Max_category_P (PCT40.1).
recode N_missing (miss=0).
exe.

*now you can return to the original data to start over with a new analysis.
dataset activate origData.
```

Comment: This works! I will flag it as correct but I have one extra question. If I wanted to create several "tables" such as this, should I create it, load the dataset again, and then create the next one? Or can I leave the original data unchanged and then activate it again somehow? Thanks

Comment: You should learn to work with datasets - I'll edit my answer to show you how  to keep the original data alongside the new table.